# SQLCommand parameter is throwing "InvalidCastException"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqlparameter

I have an old C# application that stopped working when updating the database using `SqlCommand`. I pull in a user object and update the values in a MSSQL database.

The error I'm receiving is below

> EventSink 'command.EventSink' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CommandEventSink {System.InvalidCastException}

Here's the SqlConnection code.

```cs
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Subcriptions"].ToString());

using (con)
{
    con.Open();
    StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
    builder1.Append("UPDATE dbo.Subscribers SET ");
    builder1.Append("Name = @Name,");
    builder1.Append("Email = @Email,");
    builder1.Append("Company = @Company,");
    builder1.Append("Active = @Active ");
    builder1.Append("WHERE SiebelUserId = @UserId");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(builder1.ToString(), con);
    command.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Company", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit);
    command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = user.Username;
    command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
    command.Parameters["@Email"].Value = user.Email;
    command.Parameters["@Company"].Value = user.CompanyName;
    command.Parameters["@Active"].Value = user.IsActive;
    try
    {
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        if (rowsAffected == 0)
        {
            Program.WriteLog(rowsAffected + " SQL Record not updated.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception1)
    {
        sendAdminEmail("SQL update error: " + exception1.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

I assume the `InvalidCastException` is for the `SqlDbType.Bit` having a problem with the `user.IsActive` which is Boolean. When I take that parameter out of the query I still get 0 records updated. I'm beginning to wonder if this code ever worked.

I have tried converting the boolean `User.IsActive` to an `int`.

```cs
int active;

if (user.IsActive == true)
{
    active = 1;
} else
{
    active = 0;
}

command.Parameters["@Active"].Value = active;
```

I have tried to change the cast of the `@Active` parameter to `<UInt32>`. I have tried changing the parameter to a varchar and the bool to a string "true". I have tried writing everything into the stringbuilder with lots of quotes.

Any suggestions or documentation would help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does a record matching `@UserId` actually exist?

Comment: _"I assume InvalidCastException is for the SqlDbType.Bit"_ - what lead you to make that assumption? What data or evidence to you have to pinpoint it to that specific parameter?

Comment: @Dai I think that the Bit is the only type that's not varchar.

Comment: @Dai The type mismatch is not the problem. You're investigation made me question if the error broke the flow. While the error appears, it seems to complete without a problem. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What is the datatype of your `SiebelUserId` column?  Might that be an `INT` or `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column different from `user.Username`?

Comment: Please show the full table definition, as well as the C# definition for the `User` class. Side notes: your code is unnecessarily verbose. You can put the connection directly in a `using` and you don't need to dispose it separately if you do that: `using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....` The `StringBuilder` is unnecessary, and implies that you might decide to do some SQL injection, which is a bad idea. Just use a `string` constant instead. The parameters can be added like this `command.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, lengthOfYourVarcharHere).Value = user.Username;`

Answer (score -1):

if "Active" is bit in sql and boolean in c# use:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = user.IsActive;
```

Comment: How is it different from what the OP has shown?

Answer (score -2):

While the code produces an error, it completes as expected.

The 'InvalidCastException'error is not a dealbreaker, I believe while the param may mismatch, it is included anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).